# Find $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^{\pi} - x^e}{x-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have trouble calculating this limit algebraically (without L'Hospital's rule):

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^{\pi} - x^e}{x-1}$$

Substituting 1 gives indeterminate form. If this was e.g. $(x^5 - x^2)$ in the numerator, one could easily factor out the $(x-1)$, because $(x^5 - x^2) = x^2 (x - 1) (x^2 + x + 1)$. But I don't know what to do in my problem, because the exponents are not integers.

EDIT: The problem is from a calculus textbook and is before derivatives are introduced so I assume it can be found without derivatives.

Comment: Ideally you should be aware of the formula $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^{n} - a^{n}} {x-a} =na^{n-1},a>0,n\in\mathbb{R}$$ with or without proof (depending on your course structure and textbook). And then the current problem is solved almost instantly.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: write
$$ \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{\pi}-x^e}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{\pi}-1}{x-1}-\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^e-1}{x-1}$$
and then note that each term is a derivative.

Comment: +1.  Slick!  But do we have to worry about how $x^e$ and $x^\pi$ are defined?

Comment: Depending on the OP's level, he/she may be content to use the power rule as a black box. But yes, a formal proof will require deciding on how to define $x^a$ for general $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The problem is from a calculus textbook and is before derivatives are introduced so I assume it can be found without derivatives, can't it?

Comment: That would have been good to include in the question. Also, as I mentioned above, any full solution of the problem will require carefully defining $x^{\pi}$ and $x^e$.

Comment: @carmichael561 Could you give me a reference to read up on why a careful definition of $x^a$ is necessary, or how that is even up for defining?

Comment: Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* is a good source. The most common choices are $x^a=\sup\{x^q:q<a,q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$, or first define $e^x$ and $\log x$ and then set $x^a=e^{a\log x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so for integer $n$, its clear 
$$\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\to n$$ for a fraction $\frac{p}{q}$ let $x=y^q$ and then 
$$\frac{x^{\frac{p}{q}}-1}{x-1}=\frac{y^p-1}{y^q-1}\to \frac{p}{q}$$
Now for any $a$ we have

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1^+}\frac{x^a-1}{x-1}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^+}\sup\{\frac{x^r-1}{x-1}|r\in \mathbb{Q}, r<a\}$$
$$=\sup\{\lim\limits_{x\to 1^+}\frac{x^r-1}{x-1}|r\in \mathbb{Q}, r<a\}=a$$ thus your limit is $$\pi-e$$

Answer (score 0):

Try

$$\lim_{x\to 1}x^{e}\frac{x^{\pi-e}-1}{x-1}$$

Now it depends on what you are "allowed" to use. If you assume binomial expansion works for real exponends, then that's it (this is the Taylor expansion, or the well-known first order approximation $(1+\epsilon)^n\approx 1+n\epsilon$).